# Allow user registration through our server side application only not though client side library(e.g. strophe)

Tags: xmpp, chat, ejabberd, strophe

in our system we administer users with our own logic. User's can be registered in our system and have dependencies to other entities. It checks the validity and authenticity of the user's data and is responsible for the user's master data and so on.

Now each user should also get an `ejabberd` account. What we want to do is: Use Smack in our logic and create an account in `ejabberd`. The problem is, that a user could by pass our logic and directly register an account in `ejabberd`. However, we want to keep `ejabberd` users and our users synchronous and don't want to allow account registration through any XMPP client(e.g strophe.js) but only via our system.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

The best approach is to write a custom authentication plugin in ejabberd to use your backend or to use ejabberd contrib ejabberd_auth_http: https://github.com/processone/ejabberd-contrib/tree/master/ejabberd_auth_http

You can also always create users in ejabberd from your backend and disable mod_register in ejabberd, but I would not recommend that approach as you would duplicate your user base.

Comment: disabling `mod_register` will disable user registration from browser clients and only from server side ?

Comment: Disabling mod_registed disable registration from c2s XMPP protocol (standard c2s connection, or bosh)

Comment: ...and also how can i disable `mod_register` in ejabarrd?

Comment: Comment out mod_register from ejabberd config file module section.